# Async Ajax Request Blocks Navigator?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the following code, where I try to get some data through 'whatever.php'. This php file spends about 20 seconds getting the database request. Until the server answers with the data, the navigator is blocked (if I make it asynchronous, it allows me to make a click or to fill an input, but it only redirects after the mentioned 20 seconds). I tried aborting this ajax instance, but after aborting, it waits that time too.

What I'm trying to do, is that if a user doesn't want to wait for the request being done and the table being shown, he should be able to open a link to other subpage.

```
var contenidoAjax = $('div#table_solicitudes').html('<p><img src="'.URL.'images/ajax-loader.gif" /></p>');
var instanciaAjax=$.ajax({   
url: whatever.php, 
success: function(data) {   
    if (data == "bad") {
        $('div#table_solicitudes').html("Went bad");
    }
    else {  
        $('div#table_solicitudes').html(data);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please remove the escaping from your code

Comment: What exactly is the difference between making your request asyncronous (isn't it already?) and the intended behaviour?

Comment: Yes, it is asynchronous. That's why I am making the question. Should this code work as I understand?

Comment: Yes, this does not freeze the browser, and the user can navigate to other pages / open new tabs etc. When navigating away, your request would be aborted

Comment: Sorry to tell this.. but it isn't working like that. I made a capture with wireshark, and it shows that server only answers the click request (for a redirection) after answering the other request (and this lasts 20 undesirable seconds). Maybe server configuration should fix something? Any ideas?

Comment: Uh, that sounds crazy. You could try something like `$(window).unload(function(){instanciaAjax.abort();})`, but I don't know anything about servers

Comment: I solved the problem. It had something to do with sessions. As Bergi said, my code should work without problems. I post here a link to the page[1] where I found the solution for people who could have the same problem. I dont know if it is allowed (moderate it if it is not). 

    

Thanks everybody!


  [1]: http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/

Comment: @user1696783 - You're allowed to answer your own question below :)

Comment: Not by the moment! Im not allowed to answer my own question until 8 hours have passed since the question was made :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use "beforeSend" and "complete" methods to show and hide indicator.

**Example :**

```
$.ajax({   
   url: whatever.php, 
   beforeSend: function(){
      $('div#table_solicitudes').html('<p><img src="'.URL.'images/ajax-loader.gif" /></p>'); // add indicator
   },
   complete: function(){
      $('div#table_solicitudes').html(""); // remove indicator
   }
   // existing stuff
}
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Thanks, but it had nothing to do with that, as I am going to post in a separated answer.